# How to use Tcl regexp to match an empty string?

Tags: tcl

I need TCL regular expression `regexp` to return me a 1 if and only if the input is totally empty.

I tried `regexp ^(?![\s\S])` but it doesn’t work.

Comment: Why do you need to use regexp to do this?

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
regexp {^$} $data
```

?

That said, the last time I checked, one of the most performing ways to run an emtpy-string test was using [`[string length]`](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm#M33):

```
expr {[string length $data] == 0}
```

Comment: Also check out the [Tcl wiki](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/is%5Fempty) on this subject matter.

Answer (score 0):

Test this out: `regexp {^(?!(.))}`

It’s working fine. Expectation should be met (to match an empty string/input)